# Javascript `==` will never attempt to convert its operands to false, but?

Tags: javascript

I am reading the basics of JavaScript, and I don't seem to understand this statement. The statement is given in *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition*, on page 47.

It says JavaScript's `==` never attempts to convert its operands to boolean. But when you try doing:

```
var bool = true;
var boolConv = (bool == undefined);
console.log(boolConv); //-> returns false.
```

so here `undefined` is being converted to `false` and then the comparison is happening right? So does this mean the `==` is indeed converting `undefined` to false, contrary to what was written in the book?

I did indeed test this too,

```
var bool = false;
var boolConv = (bool == undefined);
console.log(boolConv); //-> returns false.
```

The above snippet gives false too. So that's my question if both these cases are returning false, what's happening in the comparison? Why are they both returning `false`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There are no conversions involved in the expression `bool == undefined`.

Comment: What makes you think that true should be equal to undefined?

Comment: Round brackets have precedence, which is why ther are evaluated first. The result of the evalution is assigned to boolConv. True / false are not the same as undefined. (Undefined means undefined as in the English word).

Comment: If I ask you: is a zebra equal to an apple, what would you answer? That is what you are asking javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve answered your own question. If `undefined == true` is `false` and `undefined == false` is `false`, `==` apparently isn’t converting `undefined` to either `true` or `false`.

This actually just reaches the last step of the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> 10. Return `false`.

since there’s no case to compare values of type Undefined and Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

There are no conversions involved in the expression `bool == undefined`. The JavaScript interpreter is just telling you that `true` is not equal to `undefined`. It's not, so there's nothing unexplained here. The same is true when you compare `false` to `undefined`. They are not equal, either.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt converts its operand to a boolean (true or false) it creates a new value, if you

> console.log(bool);

bool stills true or false, with boolConv you created a new variable, that will be true if the comparison is true, and false if it isnt. bool is true, not undefined so boolConv is false, but bool stills true.